# Minecraft: Item not registering

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

So I'm creating a mod in Minecraft. It registers the sword but doesn't appear in the game. What can I do to make it appear in he game? Thanks in advance.

```
package com.ethan.main;

import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.item.Item.ToolMaterial;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemSword;
import net.minecraftforge.common.util.EnumHelper;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.event.FMLPreInitializationEvent;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry;

@Mod(modid = "elemental_swords", version = "1.0 Alpha", name = "Elemental Swords Mod")
public class ElementalSwords {
    public static final String modid = "elemental_swords";
    public static Item lightningsword;
    public static ToolMaterial Element = EnumHelper.addToolMaterial("Element", 9, 1378, 1000, 10, 5);


    public void preInit(FMLPreInitializationEvent event){
        lightningsword = new LightningSword(Element, "lightningsword");
        GameRegistry.registerItem(lightningsword, "Lightning Sword");
    }

    public void init(FMLInitializationEvent event){

    }
}
```

Here is the `Item` Class:

```
package com.ethan.main;

import net.minecraft.creativetab.CreativeTabs;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.item.Item.ToolMaterial;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemSword;

public class LightningSword extends ItemSword{
    public LightningSword(ToolMaterial material, String name) {
        super(material);

        setUnlocalizedName(ElementalSwords.modid + "_" +name);
        setTextureName(ElementalSwords.modid + ":" + name);

    }



}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that people are only downvoting because you mentioned Minecraft. So far as I can tell, this is a perfectly valid, on-topic question: You provide all of (and only) the necessary code, you clearly state your problem, and you were polite.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you did not put the @EventHandler annotation on the preInit and init methods. Here's how your code should look like:

```java
@EventHandler //Important
public void preInit(FMLPreInitializationEvent event) {
   //Read configs here.
}

@EventHandler
public void init(FMLInitializationEvent event) {
   //Register blocks and items here.
}
@EventHandler
public void postInit(FMLPostInitializationEvent event) {
   //Have mod integeration here.
}
```

Also, when registering blocks and items, avoid spaces.
Example: `GameRegistry.registerItem(lightningsword, "Lightning Sword");`

should be 
`GameRegistry.registerItem(lightningsword, "lightningSword");`

Also, as pointed out by @FerretBitStudios, you need to set the creative tab to show in. If you do not, the only way to get the item is through NEI or the `/give` command.

Answer (score 0):

To get your item to show up in your creative inventory, use `lightningsword.setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabCombat)` or another creative tab. Also, I know you haven't hit this roadblock yet, but I assume you're using forge for 1.8, in which case settexturename() won't work. 1.8 uses a json model system for rendering items. There's a great tutorial on it over [here](http://www.wuppy29.com/minecraft/1-8-tutorial/updating-1-7-to-1-8-part-2-basic-items/#sthash.IW6P4Cyl.dpbs). Hope it helps :)